# SQL ERROR CODE1222 Multiple select statemtns

Tags: sql, mysql-workbench

Here are my 2 tables within the database

Table: bridgebarcodes
Columns:
ID int(11) AI PK 
ProductCode varchar(100) 
Barcode varchar(100)

Table: outerbarcodes
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
ProductCode varchar(100) 
Brand varchar(100) 
Product varchar(100) 
size varchar(100) 
Barcode varchar(100)

This is what I need to do:
I need to find all barcode values from bridgebarcodes that do not exist inside outerbarcodes.
This is the code I have used to do so...

```
`select productcode, barcode from outerbarcodes where not exists(select 1
from bridgebarcodes
where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode)`
```

BUT
After that query has been executed, the table will show two columns: product code and barcode. And the problem is within column named productcode, becasue there are fields with no data. And I need to get rid of rows with empty fields even if other fields are empty within outerbarcodes table
And thats the code I have used:

```
`SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode FROM outerbarcodes WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> ''`
```

then i tried combining the two together like this:

```
`select productcode, barcode from outerbarcodes where not exists(select 1
from bridgebarcodes
where bridgebarcodes.barcode = outerbarcodes.barcode
)
union
SELECT productcode, Brand, product, size, barcode FROM outerbarcodes WHERE
COALESCE(productcode, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(Brand, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(product, '') <> '' AND
COALESCE(size, '') <> ''`
```

It gives me an error message of ERROR CODE: 1222

Comment: Marked as duplicate, please see the other question and you'll see that you've made the same mistake as them.

Comment: Thanks JeffUk ill have a look into it